# My JavaScript asynchronous function is executed twice with webpack

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, webpack

My javascript asynchronous function is executed twice but I can't figure out why.
I am using webpack and only one file is loaded on the page this is my articles.js

```
// articles.js
async function test() {
    console.log('test');
}

test().then((items) => {
    // code here
}
```

I have twice "test" in the console

```
// webpack.config.js
const path = require("path");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    entry: {
        app: "./src/index.js",
        articles: "./src/js/pages/articles.js",
    },
    output: {
        filename: "[name].bundle.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    },
    plugins: [new MiniCssExtractPlugin()],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
                use: [
                    // Translates CSS into CommonJS
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    "css-loader",
                    // Compiles Sass to CSS
                    "sass-loader",
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
};
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Does this work correctly without webpack?

Comment: I tried on codepen and it works fine.

Comment: I have also tried putting a synchronous function in my code and it is only executed once.
this concerns in the asynchronous function only.